# ListPlot3D of a set of points in a non-convex region

Tags: plotting, interpolation, computational-geometry

I would like to plot a set of points in the same style as `ListPlot3D` does, but only in a non-convex region that I can specify (e.g. using a `RegionFunction`).  Is there a simple solution for this?

Let me illustrate with an example.

Let's generate some sample points ...

```
Clear[regionFun]
regionFun[{x_, y_}] := y < x^2

fun[{x_, y_}] := -Norm[{x, y} - {.5, .5}]

pts = Select[Tuples[Range[0, 1, 0.01], 2], regionFun];
```

... and try to plot then in the region we're interested in:

```
ListPlot3D[
 Append[#, fun[#]] & /@ pts,
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, regionFun[{x, y}]],
 InterpolationOrder -> 1
]
```

[image]

Notice that the plot occupies the complete convex hull of the points because of how the Delaunay triangulation was constructed for the interpolation.

What I would like to see instead is this:

```
Plot3D[fun[{x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, regionFun[{x, y}]]]
```

[image]

The only possible solution I see at the moment is to use an external tool to "manually" construct a Delaunay triangulation which is confined within a region and build the plot from that data.  This, however, is a lot of work, so I thought I'd ask first if there's a simple solution.

Note that this is just a generated example dataset, not my real data.  I can't use `Plot3D` for my real application, only `ListPlot3D` and related functions.

Comment: Interpolation + Plot3D works.

Comment: @rm-rf For a arbitrary point cloud on an unstructured grid we will have to accept the `Interpolation::udeg` message too! `Interpolation`order will be constrained to one.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Right, but Szabolcs used order 1 anyway, so that shouldn't be a problem here. Szabolcs, I don't understand why you said you don't get nice plots... with `ifun = Interpolation[Append[#, fun[#]] & /@ pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(Indeterminate &), 
    "WarningMessage" -> False}];` and `MaxRecursion -> 6`, I get a plot that's as good as the native `Plot3D`.

Comment: @PlatoManiac All built-in `List*` plotting functions that work on 2D data will only do linear interpolation for unstructured grids, so it's the same thing.

Comment: @rm-rf I also don't understand why I don't get nice plots for my real data, but I don't.  This example I posted works perfectly.  I guess my real data is nastier: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xn79zcpnz81711/Screenshot%202013-11-10%2016.33.05.png  Regardless, I'd accept your answer if you posted it as I'm using it now.  (I did increase PlotPoints and MaxRecursion --- I think somehow the higher-than-order-1 adaptive sampler of Plot3D doesn't work well with the order-1 interpolation)

Comment: @Szabolcs Looks like the region function is not being applied... Is that the case? Can you link to a sample dataset?

Comment: @rm-rf In the screenshot, the first one is DensityPlot+Interpolation, which give s "rough plot" in the correct region.  The second one is ListDensityPlot, which isn't rough in the same way but it doesn't obey the RegionFunction.

Comment: @rm-rf Okay, here we go: the [sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38623/sample.wdx), in `{"points" -> ..., "values" -> ...}` format, contains a set of points and a set of values to be plotted at each points location.  The plotting needs to be done using the transformed `{Sqrt[#1], #2}& @@@ points`, and the region is anything that falls inside the convex hull of the untransformed points, i.e. ``Function[{x, y}, inPolygonQ[hull, {x^2, y}]]`` where `hull = ConvexHull[points]`.  `inPolygonQ` can be the built-in, undocumented one you can find using ``?*`InPolygonQ``.

Comment: @rm-rf But please don't bother unless you really want to.  I'm using your suggestion now and when I have time I'll build a better one using constrained Delaunay triangulations available in MATLAB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `Interpolation` with `Plot3D` and slightly increasing the `MaxRecursion` gives you a nice plot. Since you have an unstructured grid, the interpolation order will be restricted to 1.

```
ifun = Interpolation[Append[#, fun[#]] & /@ pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(Indeterminate &), "WarningMessage" -> False}];
Plot3D[ifun[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 6,
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, regionFun[{x, y}]]]
```

[image]